# Python requests thought client ip

Tags: javascript, django, rest, python-3.x

I have a form that a client compile and the server sends a request to a webserver that respond with a page to be parsed.

The webserver see the ip of the server that send the request, i want send those requests via client, so the webserver see her ip address and not the server ip.

I'm looking for a proxy js or websockets or a restful with endpoint, but i'm newbie! and don't understand which is right for me

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Because I am not sure what do you mean, and what is the problem.
Can't you just send requests from your client to the webserver?

Comment: ya sorry for my english^^. i want send requests using the client ip

Comment: So, you would like to get request from a server, pass it to a client and invoke on a client side and the result should be returned to the server?
I assume the client is in the browser, am I right?

Comment: I'd suggest polling the server in a loop for the requests to be handled, get them in a client and using for example XMLHttpRequest invoking them against the webserver. You can use: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp or some kind of higher level wrappers: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp